# Python kivy import error

Tags: python, kivy

I installed all the dependencies for kivy and all the things, but when i try to run my code i got this error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 318, in <module>
    from kivy.config import ConfigParser
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\config.py", line 287, in <module>
    from kivy import kivy_config_fn
ImportError: cannot import name 'kivy_config_fn'

C:\Users\Bloodyline\Desktop>pip install pygame
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
```

I tried on python 3.5 at first then on 3.4 but i get everytime the same error, googled it but anyone got my problem.

Comment: how does "pygame is already installed" indicate to you that `kivy` is installed?

Comment: How exactly did you install kivy?

Comment: I installed all the dependencies with pip, also kivy.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it's basically a bug with the deps and python64bits, just do that:
uninstall all your deps and install these:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kivy.deps.sdl2/0.1.12
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kivy.deps.glew/0.1.4

And uninstall completly gstreamer it's the main reason it won't work, just wait till it's fixed.